# ST MCU Calculating external capacitor values for oscillator on STM32F2

Tags: stm32, oscillator

Im using the equation `CL = (CL1 * CL2 / (CL1 + CL2)) + CS`  from ST AN2867 OScillator design guide to determine the external capacitor values for the main and low speed oscillators.

But for the STMF207 development board https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f207zg.html#resource the low speed oscillator capacitors fitted are 2pF for NX3215SA-32.768KHZ-EXS00A-MU00525 where CL = 6pF
And the same for the high speed oscillator; 4.3pF are fitted, NX3225GD-8.000M-EXS00A-CG04874 where CL = 8pF

Shouldn't these be ~12pF (NX3215SA^) and ~16pF (NX3225GD^) if not does the PCB add capacitance to shift the values that much? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet says Cs which includes pin and PCB wiring capacitance can roughly be approximated as 10 pF.

Therefore when a 6pF load is needed, you need 12pF of capacitance, and subtract 10pF stray, and you are left with 2pF capacitors.

The other crystal is not even mounted, but it might have more stray capacitance of 11.7pF, so 4.3pF capacitors are enough to get 16pF in total.

Comment: Can you tell me which page it says Cs=10pF. Ive searched in ST AN2867 and the MCU datasheet and cant find either Cs or 10pF. Theres a suggestion of Cs=5pF on page 13 of ST AN2867?

Comment: Try "10 pF". STM32F207ZG MCU datasheet, Rev 17, Page 91.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake, I had tunnel vision looking in the 'reference manual' and not the full datasheet. I didn't think the die to crystal would account for so much capacitance but that all makes sense.